# Creating NumPy Matrix by comprehension

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

Say I have two vectors, `x` is with `m` entries and `y` is with `n` entries. I would like to have a numpy `m x n` matrix **A**, for which,

`A[i][j]== x[i]**y[j]`

I know how to create a 2D array with list comprehension for such a problem, but is there a way to do it efficiently using numpy?
Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for `x[i]^y[i]` or dod you mean `x[i]*y[i]`?

Comment: Actually, I was looking for an answer that would also fit other functions. For example, define A[i][j]==np.linalg.norm(x[i]-y[j]), to produce a matrix of all euclidean distances of vectors taken from array x, from vectors taken from y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for the outer power you can do:

```
A=np.power.outer(x,y)
```

(assuming import numpy as np)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [numpy.outer](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) to do this

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(4) # size m
y = np.arange(5) # size n

outer_product = np.outer(x,y) # size m x n
print(outer_product)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  1  2  3  4]
[ 0  2  4  6  8]
[ 0  3  6  9 12]]
```